# Is it possible to pass in an object into angular before it initializes?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, velocity

I'm working within velocity and trying to pass info into angular app before it initializes since I cannot get access to velocity variables inside of angular. Can this be done and if so how?

p.s. I'm using require if that changes anything.

```
#set ($has_richmedia = true)
    #set ($has_navigation = true)
    #set ($root = $e.getRoot())
    <!-- getEvolutionContentAPI -->
    $e.getEvolutionContentAPI($root)
    <!-- End getEvolutionContentAPI -->
</head>

<body>

    <!-- ui-view container -->
    <div data-ui-view="root"  data-autoscroll="false"></div>

    <script src="$e.getURL('app/rconfig.js')"></script>
    <script src="$e.getURL('plugin/requirejs/require.js')" data-main="$e.getURL('app/main.js')"></script>



</body>
```

$e.getEvolutionContentAPI($root) includes a bunch of js plus including a defined js object called "de". I need "de" in my angular app.

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Comment: You can make use of global variables outside auf your angular scope. But be careful with those.

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap, it allows you to provide your angular app with a constant which you can provide through your application.